# post video to youtube

Tags: android, youtube

In our app we would like to implement direct uploading of video files to youtube without the use of the SHARE key.

Thus far I have found reference to this:
http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

but I receive this error when I try to upload a video:
http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/issues/detail?id=13

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem by creating one channel in your Youtube account(one you are using to statically login in this project).
refrences :[Ytd Project](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/issues/detail?id=2)

Comment: Are you testing it on your device or emulator?