# upload to youtube via intent

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a video to youtube using the intent.
The way I have it set is described [here](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2012/01/upload-video-to-youtube-using-send.html)

Here's snippet:

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, "My Test");
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputFile);
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
content);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
```

I would like to have the title field already set. 
Otherwise, if the user does not manually set the title field the video uploaded will have the title of the video filename.

Comment: please share the solution if you found please

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link

http://diablo-urban-o.com/post/9929911420/uploading-videos-to-youtube-from-android-part-ii

and try the following code too.

```
ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, "Test");
content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, "/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
ContentResolver resolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: the code you posted is the same I already used. And the link you posted is for setting up upload to youtube manually. Without the need for the Youtube app.

I guess if there is no other way I guess I will try to the manual approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo [application](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/) that does want you want  . Use the `ytUploader.setTitle("Android Test");` to set whatever title you want.

Comment: doesn't work. see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954901/post-video-to-youtube